# ARIMA Forecasting with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, forecasting, arima

I am trying to implement ARIMA to forecast future stock from historical data

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
future_dates = [df.index[-1] + DateOffset(day=x) for x in range(0,24) ]
future_dates_df = pd.DataFrame(index=future_dates[1:],columns=df.columns)
future_df = pd.concat([df,future_dates_df])

future_df['forecast'] = results.predict(start = 246, end = 269, dynamic= True)  
future_df[['data', 'forecast']].plot(figsize=(12, 8))
```

To which I am getting an warning:

*ValueWarning: No supported index is available. Prediction results will be given with an integer index beginning at `start`.
  ValueWarning)*

Comment: What does `df` contain?

Comment: stock data I stored it in excel and used df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

Comment: two columns: date and stock